# How can I simulate data transfer between two virtual machines using vSphere?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, file-transfer

I'm very new (about two days 'experience' consisting of troubleshooting cloning) to vSphere and virtual machines, and even networking in general.  I also need to be able to throttle the connection speed between the two machines.

I'm pretty confident this can be done, but if it simply can't be done, I'll find another way to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to change the speed of the line between them to say that the traffic can't exceed a certain throughput. You might best achieve this by throttling the speed on the uplink adapter.

[From the vSphere documentation:](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-51-networking-guide.pdf) (5.1 but it's pretty well the same across the board for versions)

```
Change the Speed of an Uplink Adapter
You can change the connection speed and duplex of an uplink adapter.
Procedure
1 Log in to the vSphere Client and select the host from the inventory panel.
2 Click the Configuration tab and click Networking.
3 Select a standard switch and click Properties.
4 Click the Network Adapters tab.
5 To change the configured speed and duplex value of a network adapter, 
  select the network adapter and click Edit.
6 To select the connection speed manually, select the speed and duplex from the
  drop-down menu.
  Choose the connection speed manually if the NIC and a physical switch might fail
  to negotiate the proper connection speed. Symptoms of mismatched speed and duplex
  include low bandwidth or no link connectivity.
  The adapter and the physical switch port it is connected to must be set to the same 
  value, such as auto and auto or ND and ND, where ND is some speed and duplex, but 
  not auto and ND.
7 Click OK.
```

Comment: First of all, I'd like to say that you it's weird seeing your own question pop up in search results.  It's even weirder forgetting you asked a question about it almost a month ago.  I'm actually getting ready to upgrade the server to 5.1 (Hypervisor), so I will try out your solution pronto.  Thanks!